# nn.Embeddings does not get trained

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

As I am creating a new NN, I used a feature embedding layer as an input layer to embed categorical features. However, I noticed that those embeddings (which should be trainable) do not get updated when I perform the training. Everything else gets updated but the embeddings.

Given that I have several categorical features, I define my FeatureEmbedder module as below.

```
class FeatureEmbedder(nn.Module):
    # Discuss if we need this implementation or if the FeatureEmbedded from gluonts.torch.model.modules.feature works
    @validated()
    def __init__(
        self,
        cardinalities: List[int],
        embedding_dimensions: List[int],
    ):
        super().__init__()
        
        self._num_embedded_features = len(cardinalities)
        self.embedders = [
            torch.nn.Embedding(num_embeddings=card, embedding_dim=dim)
            for card, dim in zip(cardinalities, embedding_dimensions)
        ]

    def forward(self, features):
        """
        :param features: (-1, num_features)
        :return:
            Embedding with shape (-1, sum([self.embedding_dimensions]))
        """
        embedded_features = torch.cat(
            [
                embedder(features[:, i].long())
                for i, embedder in enumerate(self.embedders)
            ],
            dim=-1,
        )
        return embedded_features
```

I notice that, when I first call my training function and print the model, the FeatureEmbedder submodule does not seem to have any parameter, which I do not explain ...

```
  | Name                      | Type                        | Params
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
0 | model                     | NNetwork                    | 193   
1 | model.embedder            | FeatureEmbedder             | 0     
2 | model.model               | Sequential                  | 160   
3 | model.model.0             | Linear                      | 50    
4 | model.model.1             | ReLU                        | 0     
5 | model.model.2             | Linear                      | 110   
6 | model.model.3             | ReLU                        | 0     
7 | model.output_layer        | Sequential                  | 33    
8 | model.output_layer.linear | Linear                      | 33    
9 | loss                      | ScaledNegativeLogLikelihood | 0     
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Can someone help explain why my Embeddings do not get trained with the network? I have checked and it seems to me that all tensors / embedders do require grad (xx.requires_grad is True).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Soumith explains this in a question on the [pytorch forums](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/the-difference-in-usage-between-nn-modulelist-and-python-list/7744/2). Never use lists to store weights/layers because `self.parameters` will not look in for parameters if they're in a regular list, and these are the parameters (assumably) passed to your optimizer. Use `torch.nn.ModuleList` instead.

Comment: Glad to help! Mind upvoting or accepting the answer to help future visibility?

Comment: Sadly I cannot upvote as I don't have the reputation points to do so, which is why I left a comment. Hope this helps!